# What is the relationship between dew point temp. and pressure? Do pressure decrease will result in dew point temp. Decrease or not?

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the relationship between dew point temp. and pressure? Do pressure decrease will result in dew point temp. Decrease or not?
I'm dealing with air treatment I noticed that when I reduced the pressure entering an air dryer from 125 psi to 120 psi then dew point temperature decreases from (-50.1C to -39.6C), does that pressure reduction cause all that dew point decrease or not?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a decrease in dew point because the partial pressure of the water vapor also decreases when the total pressure is reduced.  However, the change should be less than you observed.